# Integrar Addon Payments

Tags: php, javascript, html

Es la primera vez que integro Addon Payments y la verdad no consigo hacerlo funcionar, os explico más menos lo que e realizado por si me podéis ayudar.
*De momento estoy con las pruebas que te ofrece la documentación haber si logro pasar datos.*

**Este es el formulario que te da su documentación**

```
<form method="POST" action="https://hpp.sandbox.addonpayments.com/pay">
 <input type="hidden" name="TIMESTAMP" value="20181022094346">
 <input type="hidden" name="MERCHANT_ID" value="ID de comercio">
 <input type="hidden" name="ACCOUNT" value="internet">
 <input type="hidden" name="ORDER_ID" value="N6qsk4kYRZihmPrTXWYS6g">
 <input type="hidden" name="AMOUNT" value="1001">
 <input type="hidden" name="CURRENCY" value="EUR">
 <input type="hidden" name="SHA1HASH" value="308bb8dfbbfcc67c28d602d988ab104c3b08d012">
 <input type="hidden" name="AUTO_SETTLE_FLAG" value="1">
 <input type="hidden" name="COMMENT1" value="Canal móvil">
 <input type="hidden" name="COMMENT2" value="Pago inicial">
 <input type="hidden" name="SHIPPING_CODE" value="E77|4QJ">
 <input type="hidden" name="SHIPPING_CO" value="GB">
 <input type="hidden" name="BILLING_CODE" value="R90|ZQ7">
 <input type="hidden" name="BILLING_CO" value="GB">
 <input type="hidden" name="CUST_NUM" value="332a85b">
 <input type="hidden" name="VAR_REF" value="Invoice 7564a">
 <input type="hidden" name="PROD_ID" value="SKU1000054">
 <input type="hidden" name="HPP_LANG" value="GB">
 <input type="hidden" name="HPP_VERSION" value="2">
 <input type="hidden" name="MERCHANT_RESPONSE_URL" value="https://www.example.com/responseUrl">
 <input type="hidden" name="CARD_PAYMENT_BUTTON" value="Pagar ahora">
 <input type="hidden" name="SUPPLEMENTARY_DATA" value="Valor personalizado">
 <input type="submit" value="Haz clic aquí para comprar">
</form>
```

**Pero esta parte que pongo a continuación no la comprendo**

Paso 1: Con el algoritmo SHA-1, obtener el valor hash de una cadena compuesta por los valores solicitados.

La referencia del valor hash de una solicitud de HPP es:

```
"timestamp.merchantid.orderid.amount.currency"
```

Partiendo del ejemplo de POST anterior, nuestra cadena inicial será:

```
"20181022094346.ID de comercio.N6qsk4kYRZihmPrTXWYS6g.1001.EUR"
```

Paso 2: Concatenar la cadena de valores hash con el secreto compartido.

Después de realizar el paso 1, tendrás una cadena como la siguiente: 28b85cd34d0e0d6b243d58f0e9f7f4bf7da1b882

Tienes que concatenarla con el secreto compartido, por ejemplo:

```
"28b85cd34d0e0d6b243d58f0e9f7f4bf7da1b882.Secreto compartido"
```

Paso 3: Con el algoritmo SHA-1, obtener el valor hash de la cadena concatenada.

La cadena definitiva que añadimos a la solicitud ha de ser un valor hash, obtenido con el algoritmo SHA-1, de la cadena concatenada. Por ejemplo: 947903969e7aaf996164c680a6669805fe405269

Haber si alguien me puede arrojar algo de luz por que me da error en el HASH.
Aquí los datos no están actualizados, yo añado el código de comercio y el merchant id.

Comment: ¡Lo importante sería saber como obtienes el SHA-1, podrías describirlo?

Answer (score 0):

Comprobando la sintaxis que hay que seguir en la documentación oficial, veo que se debe concatenar un "." como string para calcular correctamente el hash.

Partiendo de la base que tenemos los siguientes datos:

- $timestamp = valor del tiempo en el momento de la operación; (te digo como sacarlo más abajo)
- $MERCHANT_ID = 1234567890;
- $OrderID = 1234;
- $Amount = 1001;
- $Currency = EUR;
- $SharedSecret = secret;

Para calcular el timestamp en PHP se puede utilizar la siguiente función:

```
<?php

  $timestamp = date("YmdHis");

/* El valor que devuelve es el tiempo real dependiendo la ejecución del programa, por ejemplo = 20181022094346 */

?>
```

Por lo tanto, se debe realizar el cálculo del hash de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php

  $json= $timestamp.".".$MERCHANT_ID.".".$OrderID.".".$Amount.".".$Currency;

/* Valor de $json = 20181022094346.1234567890.1234.1001.EUR; */

  $firma = sha1(sha1($json).".".$SharedSecret);

/* Valor de $firma = ea5141f2fb75098774806d27e8f43968deb4dfca */

?>
```

El valor de "$firma" se debe incluir en el input HTML "SHA1HASH":

```
<input type="hidden" name="SHA1HASH" value="<?php $firma; ?>">
```